# JFreeChart insert two lines text

Tags: java, charts, report, jfreechart, pie-chart

Is it possible to insert two lines center text in PieChart of JFreeChart?

When I do `chart.setCenterText("Test\nTest");`, the text appears in the same line ([Chart result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgjyF.png)).

Comment: I don't see any support, but you can override the ring plot's `drawItem()`.

Comment: Do you see any easy way to do it?

Comment: Sadly, no; these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20recapitulate) illustrate the typical approach.